# How does method Object.defineProperty prevents properties from rewriting

Tags: javascript

How does Object.defineProperty works for rewriting props. Is it implemented using js mechanisms (Is it possible to implement the same functionality using js ?)?

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.defineproperty ?

Comment: Thanks, @zerkms.But what I'm am interested to know, whether this functionality (rewriting object's props) is done on a language level or during compilation.

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX!!  So can you please provide some short example (customDefineProperty) of how to implement the same functionality let say only for rewriting object's props, but making this custom function behaves the same. I mean doing something like:  customDefineProperty(obj, 'name', {writable: false})   obj.name = "str" should not change the value of property name

Comment: @JaromandaX :))) let customDefineProperty = Object.defineProperty -  it's not an implementation it's just a reference for the native function. By implementation, I mean custom function with body, without using native methods. In other words, imagine that you need to make same functionality for some IE 2 or 3 and as it doesn't support Object.defineProperty you will need to write some polyfill, is it possible just by using js ? Is it possible to repeat the same behavior?

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` is the only way to do this - it is not polyfillable - you can emulate its functionality of creating properties, but you can't emulate the functionality of making things readonly/non-enumerable/non-configurable

Comment: @JaromandaX that's what I was asking about. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does `Object.defineProperty` works for rewriting props.

By accessing the internal definition of the property (called "property attributes" in the spec).

> Is it implemented using js mechanisms, and is it possible to implement the same functionality using js?

No. `Object.defineProperty` is a primitive building block of the language.